# Not able to add component dynamically to view in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to do a HTTP call to an api,based on the data returned,I need to render images dynamically.can i add for loop in render function and achieve this.
regards
Khegde

Answer (score 2):

While you can use a `for` loop, it's cleaner and more functional to use a `map` instead.

```
render: function() {
  var images = ['a.png', 'b.png', ...];
  return (
    <View>
      {images.map((source, i) => (<Image key={i} source={source} />))}
    </View>
  );
}
```